# Php code igniter save turkish characters to my sql

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, encoding, turkish

I am writing a web app using PHP Codeigniter. I receive input that can be in any language and I save it in my DB.

The MYSQL DB collation is set to utf8_unicode_ci. 
For codeigniter in the database.php I have set this:

```
$db['default']['char_set'] = 'utf8';
$db['default']['dbcollat'] = 'utf8_unicode_ci';
```

When I run the following insert on my DB:

```
insert into user (name,id) values ('John Temirtaş', 2)
```

I get this error:

> Incorrect string value: '\xC5\x9F' for column 'name' at row 1

There is a problem with the s. Its a turkish character.

So far I have tried this while debugging

```
print_r($name)
John Temirtaş

print_r("Encoded Name: ".utf8_encode($name))
Encoded Name: John TemirtaÅ

print_r("Decoded Name".utf8_decode($name)
Encoded Name: John Temirta?

print_r("Decoded-Encode Name: ".utf8_decode(utf8_encode($name)))
Decoded-Encode Name: John Temirtaş
```

I have tried saving John TemirtaÅ in the db and it works fine. So I think I might `utf8_encode($name)` before saving it in the DB and utf8_decode before displaying it. Just doing the latter will NOT work. YOU NEED TO ADD `mb_internal_encoding("UTF-8");` to the top of your php script.

How do I encode the data properly so that its inserted?

---

**THANK YOU EVERYONE FOR YOU HELP HERE IS WHAT WORKED!**

1. Open up MySql work bench. Set the
   character encoding and collation of
   the user table. Charset: utf-8
   Collation: utf8_unicode_ci
2. Set the collation of the **name** column
   to **utf8_unicode_ci**. Done. The
   insert should work.

Thank you for all your help.

Comment: Make sure your file encoding where you make insert query also in UTF-8

Comment: @Anatoly I added mb_internal_encoding("UTF-8"); at the top of the page but it did not work.

Comment: I have added your self-answer to your question. In the future, please add any relevant information by **editing** your question (look for "edit" link), instead of posting it as an answer or comment. Good luck with your situation!

Comment: Save you php file in UTF-8 encoding. You must set encoding of your php file in editor. e.g.: then your save php file in notepad, your must choose UTF-8 encoding in options.

Comment: @Anatoly I use Notepad++ to edit my code. Are you saying that I should set the encoding of my php file to UTF-8 there. Sorry I might be misunderstanding, why code be editor dependent.

Answer (score 1):

Before running your insert query, try running the following query first:

```
mysql_query("SET NAMES 'utf8'");
```

and seeing if that helps.

Answer (score 1):

You did everything okay. I am from turkey and in every project I develop I am checking these things:

- Is my **php file** saving with **UTF8 encode**?
- Are my tables and its fields collated with **utf8_unicode_ci**

Do not change codeigniter's **"char_set"** and **"dbcollat"** options.

If you do these, there should be no problem.

Comment: what do you mean by my "Is my php file saving with UTF8 encode?". How do I ensure that?

Comment: simply open the php file with notepad. Then File > Save As. Ensure that the encoding type beneath the file name input box, is utf8. It should be ANSI for default. Or you can use notepad++. open the file with notepad++ and Encode > Convert to UTF8. then save it.

Answer (score 1):

Try this before inserting record in databse.

```
$this->db->db_set_charset('latin1', 'latin1_swedish_ci');

// -> latin1- Charset & 
// -> latin1_swedish_ci - Collation
```

Make sure you have same setting in DB for table as well as for table column.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe I cannot answer exactly to what you are asking but I can give a few general tips cause I use utf-8 my self.

1. Try entering this character by hand from some client (heidisql is a free one).
2. When I worked with GET things didn't work well but with htmlencode, htmlspecialchars.. with such functions it works fine.
3. Later I only worked with POST so no encoding required and I have implemented an utf-8 autocomplete that works fine.

I thing it is worth to try the encoding thing and var_dump sql just before insert in order to make sure what is entered.

1. In some complex situtation quotes stored in variables have come very handy to me, for example:

   $dbq="\"";
   $sql=$dbq .'some sql '. $dbq;

I work with PHP PDO and never had a problem with utf-8 so far. Hope any of this is of some help!

I forgot.. you said codeIgniter.. entering a value by hand  will assure you at least where to focus, db or framework (luckily I use mine mvc). Just try to get very inside into the mvc code and see what does sql look like just before insertion.